# Firebase Functions Pubsub and Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

I have made a web scraping function in NodeJS that gets the inventory of a given product from the site of a store using puppeteer.

This is the function:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const scraper = async (productId, offerId) => {
    const url = `url`;
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox'] });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);

    const inventory = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const selectBox = document.querySelector('inventory');

        if (selectBox) {
            return Number(selectBox.value);
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    });

    if (inventory === 500) {
        const currentInventory = await page.$$eval('real inventory', (elements) => {
            const element = elements.find((element) => isNaN(element.innerHTML) === false);

            if (element) {
                return element.innerHTML;
            } else {
                return inventory;
            }
        });

        await browser.close();

        return currentInventory;
    } else {
        await browser.close();

        return inventory;
    }
};

module.exports = scraper;
```

Now I am making a Firebase Pubsub function that gets all stored products from the Firestore, then gets the inventory of all products and stores the inventory in the Firestore.

This is the Pubsub function:

```js
const request = require('request');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const serviceAccount = require('./accountKey.json');

/**
 * Connects the Firebase project to the server
 */
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});

const db = admin.firestore();

/**
 * Gets the curent inventory for the given product from site
 * @param productId The product id from the wanted product
 * @param offerId The offer id from the wanted product
 * @returns {Promise<number>}
 */
const getInventory = async (productId, offerId) => {
    return await new Promise(async (resolve) => {
        await request(
            { url: `${functions.config().tracker.serviceurl}/${productId}/${offerId}` },
            (error, response, body) => {
                if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
                    console.error('Error GET: ', error);
                    resolve(-1);
                }

                resolve(JSON.parse(body).stock);
            },
        );
    });
};

/**
 * Gets all the products from the Firestore
 * @returns {Promise<boolean>}
 */
const getProducts = async () => {
    const snapshot = await db
        .collection('products')
        .get()
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error: ', error);
            return false;
        });
    snapshot.forEach((document) => {
        getProductInventory(document.data()).catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error 2: ', error);
        });
    });
    return true;
};

/**
 * Gets the inventory of the given product from the Firestore
 * @param product The wanted product
 * @returns {Promise<boolean>}
 */
const getProductInventory = async (product) => {
    const offerId = offerId;
    const trackerId = trackerId;

    const document = await db
        .collection('productInventory')
        .doc(trackerId)
        .get()
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error 3: ', error);
            return false;
        });

    const newInventory = Number(await getInventory(product.id, offerId));
    const isSold = newInventory !== -1;

    let productInventory = [];
    const newProductInventory = {
        inventory: isSold ? newInventory : 0,
        price: price,
        numberOfSales: 0,
        updated: new Date(),
    };

    if (document.exists) {
        productInventory = document.data().productInventory;

        const oldInventory = productInventory[productInventory.length - 1].inventory;

        newProductInventory.numberOfSales = productInventory[productInventory.length - 1].numberOfSales;
        newProductInventory.inventory = isSold ? newInventory : productInventory[productInventory.length - 1].inventory;

        if (newInventory < oldInventory && isSold) {
            const numberSold = oldInventory - newInventory;

            if (newProductInventory.numberOfSales !== 0) {
                newProductInventory.numberOfSales += numberSold;
            } else {
                newProductInventory.numberOfSales = numberSold;
            }
        }
    }

    productInventory.push(newProductInventory);

    return await setProductInventory(productInventory, trackerId);
};

/**
 * Sets the inventory of a product
 * @param newProductInventory The new inventory for the product
 * @param trackerId The wanted product
 * @returns {Promise<boolean>}
 */
const setProductInventory = async (newProductInventory, trackerId) => {
    await db
        .collection('productInventory')
        .doc(trackerId)
        .set({ productInventory: newProductInventory })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error('Error: 5', error);
            return false;
        });
    return true;
};

module.exports = getProducts;
```

I am calling the inventory function at the hosted Firebase function url because if I call the function directly like this:

> const getInventory = (productId, offerId) => {
> return scraper(productId, offerId);
> };

I will get the error: "Could not get inventory:  TimeoutError: Timed out after 30000 ms while trying to connect to the browser! Only Chrome at revision r856583 is guaranteed to work."

This is because of Puppeteer.

However I have the inventory function deployed on Firebase functions as a http request function and I am calling it in the Pubsub function.

And it works sometimes but I still get an error regularly:
[Firebase function console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1povI.png)

"Exception from a finished function: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0"

and

"Error GET:  Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established"

and the

"ECONNRESET".

Everything works fine locally however I cannot get Puppeteer working in the pubsub function.
Does anyone know how to call puppeteer directly in a pubsub function or how to fix the issue with calling puppeteer on http request in a pubsub function? Thank you in advance!

Here is my index.js aswell:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');
const scraper = require('./scraper');
const getProducts = require('./service');
const app = express();
const port = 5000;

/**
 * Sets header for all server requests
 */
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    next();
});

/**
 * Initial server screen
 */
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Welcome to the server!');
});

/**
 * Search product endpoint
 */
app.get('/api/search/:query', (req, res) => {
    request(
        {
            url: `${functions.config().tracker.apiurl}/search?q=+${req.params.query}&apikey=${
                functions.config().tracker.apikey
            }`,
        },
        (error, response, body) => {
            if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
                return res.status(500).json({ type: 'error', message: error.message });
            }

            res.json(JSON.parse(body));
        },
    );
});

/**
 * Get inventory for given product endpoint
 */
app.get('/inventory/:productId/:offerId', async (req, res) => {
    res.send({
        stock: await scraper(req.params.productId, req.params.offerId),
    });
});

/**
 * Set server port
 */
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port: ${port}`);
});

/**
 * Runtime options server
 */
const runtimeOpts = {
    timeoutSeconds: 300,
    memory: '1GB',
};

// Server region
const REGION_NAME = 'europe-west1';

/**
 * CRON job to get all products inventory every 30 min.
 * Deployed at Firebase Functions.
 */
exports.service = functions
    .region(REGION_NAME)
    .runWith({
        memory: '4GB',
        timeoutSeconds: 0,
    })
    .pubsub.schedule('*/30 * * * *')
    .timeZone('Europe/Amsterdam')
    .onRun(async () => {
        async function init() {
            await getProducts();
        }

        await init();
    });

//Sets server on Firebase functions
exports.app = functions.region(REGION_NAME).runWith(runtimeOpts).https.onRequest(app);
```